# How to Import Razorpay Plugin in phaser ES6

Tags: phaser-framework, razorpay

I'm developing phaser mobile games using phaser ES6. Right Now i try to implement Razorpay. This is the link [https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova] given from Razorpay side.

This is the code for installing plugin.

> cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova --save

After That i don't know how to add plugin into my code. Anyone have a knowledge about razorpay phaser integration.

Comment: I have coded a game in cordova with Phaser 2 (CE), you just need to put the file `phaser.min.js` in a folder then add the `<script src="libs/phaser.min.js"></script>` in your index.html checkout my GitHub repos you'll find some examples